# Create a grid like table for data input in html, which will be inserted into sql

Tags: html, sql

I want to create an HTML that consists of a cell grid like an Excel sheet. The user should be able to add more rows or columns dynamically.

Once the user enters all the data into the cells and hits submit, all of it will be used to create a new SQL table and enter the data into it.

Basically, every user gets to customize their tables and add it into the database, using the HTML.

How can this be done with HTML and sql

I understand this can be done if I put the info into an excel file and upload it to the server but I want it to be done right on the server

Comment: Are you using any backend language, like forming an application. Or you want direct conversion from html to SQL?

Comment: I am using Python Flask, if i get the html data into python, process it and then put it into the SQL, that works too.

Comment: You should tag python and explain the flow of application. To help us understand better and provide you with an answer. You can use javascript or text fields for input from user on NUmber of rows and column. then create table with those stats. Retrieving data in python is another step and processing. And finally you can use stored procedures to create table and insert values